# How to get the the Scenario name from the feature file to be fetch stepdefinition java code

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd

I wanted to fetch the text name of scenario from the feature file and store it to a variable or print it in my Step Definition. Below are my code:

Feature file:

```
Feature: Login
  I want to use this template for my feature file

  Scenario Outline: Login with correct credentials
    Given the user is on the login page
```

Step Definition:

```
public class Login implements Data{
    WebDriver driver;
    LoginPage loginPage;

    @Given("^the user is on the login page$")
    public void navigateToURL() {
        System.setProperty(DRIVER, DRIVER_LOCATION);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.visit(BASE_URL);
        loginPage.clickLoginLink();

        //System.out.println("Testing Scenario" + *<scenario name>*)
    }
}
```

I wanted to print the Scenario Outline text: Login with correct credentials. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

UPDATE:
I've tried adding this code, but throws an error message:
[image: TagExpressionParser exception]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Before Hook and inside the hook print out the scenario name like below:

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

    @Before
    public void printScenarioName(Scenario scenario) {
        System.out.println("Run into Before Hook: printScenarioName");
        System.out.println("Print Scenario name in Before Hook: " + scenario.getName());
    }
```

Below are dependency into Maven pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- Test tools -->
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <!-- Cucumber version -->
    <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you not use Maven, download below jars and add them as project library
[image]

Above code worked on my local, you can get them form [my github](https://github.com/yongcy/stackoverflow/tree/print-scenario-name/cucumber/print-scenario-name)

Comment: Don't forget that the hook goes into the Step Definition file, not the Runner with the RunWith and CucumberOptions annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded cucumber jars from io.cucumber where I encountered this error. I created a new project with jars coming from info.cukes then point may build path to it. The scenario.getName() now returns the scenario name as expected. This solves my issue here.

You just need to download these jars correctly in maven repository:

```
cucumber-core - info.cukes
cucumber-java - info.cukes
cucumber-junit - info.cukes
cucumber-jvm-deps - info.cukes
cucumber-reporting - net.masterthought
gherkin - info.cukes
junit - junit
mockito-all - org.mockito
cobertura - net.sourgeforge.cobertura
```

Hope this helps.